# Images from Device storage custom path In React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an Image that I've downloaded and saved to the path `/data/user/0/com.project/files/assets/image.png` and I want to use this in my Image component in React-Native. Is there a way to use images stored in this path?

Ways to solve it that I have knowledge of but cannot use :

- using `require`. which basically accepts literal strings that is not what I want for non-static images. names may change as per image for a single image source
- using Native bundles, which is again I cannot use as the images are first being downloaded and then is being used.
- using http links directly.which as again I cannot use as my feature states that the App cannot rely on network as it needs to render images in offline mode as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's a file on your device, I think the way of displaying it is somewhat like this:

```
<Image source={{uri:'file:///data/user/0/com.project/files/assets/image.png'}} style={{width: 100, height: 100}}/>
```

Just make sure the file path is from the root. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Solved :) 
Thanks a lot